# How do you create an additional interpreter?

Tags: bash, application-development, webserver, python3, webdav

Short and sweet version: I figured breaking it down into steps would make it easier.

1. I'm building a website
2. I hate SQL. It makes no sense to me, for a programmer to have to learn an additional language for database interaction.
3. I can't stand PHP: It's too much like C and doesn't integrate well with MongoDB
4. I LOVE Python: It's simple, straight-forward, and integrates well with MongoDB
5. Python isn't built for the web: Ideally, Python would use this feature `<?python?>`, like PHP.
6. To counter number 5, I've written an interpreter (in Python) which reads a file line by line and prints everything until it finds `<?python`. Upon finding that, it starts executing Python code until it hits `?>`. Then it will resume printing the HTML lines in the file.

I've setup my CGI file to point to my new interpreter with this line:

```
#!/home/jesse/Desktop interpret
```

The interpreter itself has a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Upon execution of the CGI file, I get:

```
bash: ./test: /home/jesse/Desktop: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this problem? Are there any better ways of optimizing my scripts (besides my interpreter)?

Comment: /home/jesse/Desktop looks like a folder.

Comment: It is. I figured out what I was doing wrong. It's OK to put a space between /usr/bin/env and python but everything else needs a / between it. So /home/jesse/Desktop/interpret

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is a command, and `python` is an argument you pass to it. That's why you can put a space there. You could do `/usr/bin/env interpret` if `interpret` is in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong.

```
#!/home/jesse/Desktop interpret
```

Needed to be:

```
#!/home/jesse/Desktop/interpret
```

`/usr/bin/env` is a command itself. Python is an argument passed to it.

Thanks to @muru for this.